# Django / Postgres - Sum aggregate function duplicates results when grouping by other annotations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

The Django Sum() aggregation method produces buggy results when combined with multiple annotations that usually results in duplicated data when a row of data can fit into multiple categories

Take the following for example:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class ItemLink(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=False, related_name='parent_item_links')
    child_item  = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=False, related_name='child_item_links')

class Aggregate(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=False)
    data = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

These 3 tables describe an item, the relationship items have to other items, and some aggregate table that has data associated to a particular item.

If I were to sum the aggregate data for an item and group by any parent relationships it has, I would receive duplicate results.

For example:

```
[{
    name: parent_1,
    id: 1
},
{
    name: parent_2,
    id: 2
},
{
    name: child_1,
    data: 1.0, (via aggregate)
    id: 3
}]
```

if I were to query against this data set I would expect to get data: 1 for both the parent objects, but when I group by the items name, I get 2.

```
Aggregate.objects
    .annotate('item_name': F('item__parent_item_links__parent_item__name'))
    .annotate(agg_value=Sum('data'))
    .filter('item_id__is': 3)
    .values_list('item_name', 'agg_value')
```

would give you

```
[{
    item_name: parent_1,
    agg_value: 2.0,
},
{
    item_name: parent_2,
    agg_value: 2.0,
}]
```

where I'd expect it to instead group by the item_name and thus only give 1 for each agg_value. Any thoughts on how to work around this?

I've seen people in django bugs talk about doing this as a subquery (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:70) but that seems to only relate when you are doing multiple aggregate functions in annotations. I don't see a way to include this Sum function as a subquery.

Thanks!

Comment: Based from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses), if you just leave `.annotate(agg_value=Sum('data'))`, the aggregation will apply to all the rows so you will get 2. So you have to group them by name first before the annotation

Comment: @bdbd how do you specify the group by to Django? From what I'm reading it seems that .group_by() isn't a thing

Comment: Doing values_list is like doing values which is group by

Comment: What if I only want to return specific fields, but not include those in the group by. Is it possible to have the group by and the select be different from each other?

Comment: You can use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only). So I think you need to use the group by first, before the aggregate, then use `only` to get only the columns you need. Something like: `Aggregate.objects.annotate('item_name': F('item__parent_item_links__parent_item__name')).values('item_name').annotate(agg_value=Sum('data')).filter('item_id__is': 3).only('item_name', agg_value)`